# Dynamically add validation to form via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, parsley.js

I´m stuck. I can´t edit the html for the form, so i need to add parsley.js validation attributes after page load, but parsley doesn´t seem to run if i use it like this:

```
var myForm = "#theForm";
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {  
    if (jQuery(myForm).length) { 

      jQuery( '#user_email' ).attr( 'data-parsley-equalto', '#user_email_validate');

      jQuery( myForm ).parsley();
    }
});
```

Exchanging the validation line with the following works fine, so it seems to be a problem with the 'data-parsley-XXX' part:

```
jQuery( '#last_name' ).attr( 'minlength', 2);
```

What am i missing? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Should work. Do you have a demo/fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

@user33958 is this what you're after?

```html
<form id="theForm">
  <input id="user_email" placeholder="Email" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {  
    var myForm = jQuery("#theForm");
    if (jQuery(myForm).length) { 
      myForm.parsley();
      jQuery("#user_email").parsley().addConstraint('minlength',2);
    }
});
</script>
```

See working codepen:
http://codepen.io/ds0001/pen/NPmWoZ?editors=101